# How to Sum up a field in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables with same field but with inaccurate data. I've found the difference in price but how do I sum up the field "difference" as a different field for me to make a report on the total of the variance.

```
SELECT 
a.barcode AS BarcodeSUS, 
a.sell AS PriceSUS, 
b.price AS PricePOS, 
a.sell-b.price AS difference
FROM SUS AS a LEFT JOIN POS AS b ON a.barcode = b.barcode
ORDER BY b.price;
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(...) FROM ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the accumulated value in each row this should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    a.barcode AS BarcodeSUS
    , a.sell AS PriceSUS
    , b.price AS PricePOS
    , a.sell-b.price AS difference
    , (SELECT
        SUM(SUS.sell-POS.price)
        FROM SUS
            LEFT JOIN POS ON SUS.barcode = POS.barcode
        WHERE SUS.barcode <= a.barcode
      ) AS [accumulated difference]
FROM SUS AS a
    LEFT JOIN POS AS b ON a.barcode = b.barcode
ORDER BY a.barcode;
```

If you want the total difference only:

```
SELECT
    a.barcode AS BarcodeSUS
    , a.sell AS PriceSUS
    , b.price AS PricePOS
    , a.sell-b.price AS difference
    , (SELECT
        SUM(SUS.sell-POS.price)
        FROM SUS
            LEFT JOIN POS ON SUS.barcode = POS.barcode
      ) AS [total difference]
FROM SUS AS a
    LEFT JOIN POS AS b ON a.barcode = b.barcode
ORDER BY a.barcode;
```

*"Summing in reports"* is explained in detail here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Summing-in-reports-ad4e310d-64e9-4699-8d33-b8ae9639fbf4?omkt=en-GB&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB